# How to make hyperlink for a background image?

Tags: html, css, drupal-7

I am displaying a list of files on a page, at the end of the each file nameI have used one background image(cross mark). But I need that image should be clickable element. When I click on the image it should delete from the given path.For more details, see the below image

[image]

How can I achieve that, give some suggestion.
Below html and css code I am using to display that image

```
 $data .= '<div class = "public-file-names" ><a href="'.$path .'xmluploads/'. $foldnames .'/'. $filenames.'" target="_blank" download>' ."--". $filenames .'</a><br></div>';

div.public-file-names {


     background: transparent url("../images/close-cross.jpg") no-repeat scroll right center;
     font-size: 14px;
     margin: 10px 0;
    }
```

Comment: put on your html code

Comment: I have modified question by adding html. Please look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add another anchor tag for the delete button, then move the background image to the tag.

```
$data .= '<div class = "public-file-names" ><a href="'.$path .'xmluploads/'. $foldnames .'/'. $filenames.'" target="_blank" download>' ."--". $filenames .'</a><br><a href="" class="delete-button"></a></div>';

.public-file-names {
     font-size: 14px;
     margin: 10px 0;
}

.delete-button {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    background: transparent url("../images/close-cross.jpg") no-repeat scroll right center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery but it can be achieved by html

you could just wrap each of your .public-file-names divs in an a tag

```
<a href="your-link.html">
   <div class="public-file-names">

   </div>
</a>

<a href="your-link.html">
   <div class="public-file-names">

   </div>
</a>

<a href="your-link.html">
   <div class="public-file-names">

   </div>
</a>
```

if that doesnt work for you let me know if you want me to help you using jQuery

Comment: Please look into the, modified question which has html code also. I already using anchor tag to link the file names to particular path. How can I achieve separate link for the cross mark image.